# Search for a element inside ArrayList INSIDE Stack

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

I dont know if this is optimal,but I have to work with a stack for a exam practice, I dicided to use a Stack which contains a ArrayList Which contains ArrayLists which contain string type variables;

Later on I want to look for a single element, an ID. This is where I am stuck.
This is what I have codded for this search function:

```
  private void btn_actualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //Busqueda:
    String criterio;
    Stack <ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> pila_registro=new Stack <>(); //This is outside this class,  added it here just so you know how the stack works
    criterio=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el carne de seguro del paciente por buscar:");
    int index=pila_registro.search(criterio);
    if (index!= -1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Paciente encontrado!");
        System.out.print(index);
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente no encontrado!");
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: You are using a Stack of a 2-dimensional ArrayList. Assuming you ID is in string format, the brute force solution would be to iterate over each element in the stack, then iterate on each outer ArrayList, then iterate on each inner ArrayList and look for an ID string equal to your searched ID string. The returned value would probably be the location of the 2d array in the Stack + the location of the ID in the outer+inner ArrayLists.